# I am trying to understand the following code below

Tags: java, string, loops, conditional-statements

I am getting a different value when I am performing the iteration manually on

"welcometojava"

when the value of i=5

I am getting  following value of variable

when i=5;

```
substring =MET
smallest="com"
largest="ome"
```

At this point, the value that I am getting is not validating both the if conditions
I want help with the values of all 3 variables on each iteration so that I can know where I am getting 
wrong.Thankyou

```
public class Solution {

public static String getSmallestAndLargest(String s, int k) {
    String smallest = "";
    String largest = "";
    smallest = largest = s.substring(0, k);
    for (int i=1; i<s.length()-k+1; i++) {
        String substr = s.substring(i, i+k);
        if (smallest.compareTo(substr) > 0)
            smallest = substr;
        if (largest.compareTo(substr) < 0)
            largest = substr;
    }
    return smallest + "\n" + largest;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What did you expect and how is it different from the results you get?

Comment: You can just print the values of `substr`, `smallest`, and `largest` on each iteration?

Comment: I am trying to understand this code by executing the  code logic on paper

Comment: Your program is lexicographically compares current sub string(substr) with smallest and largest string, and it check that current sub string is smaller then existing smallest or it larger then exiting largest. What other configuration you have in this program? Both IF condition in loop get fails if "smallest < substr < largest"

Comment: Thankyou go the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using a debugger, you can trace the values by printing them e.g. I've added `System.out.println("i=" + i + ", substring=" + substr + ", smallest=" + smallest + ", largest=" + largest);` into your code as follows and also shown the output below it to help you understand how your code is behaving:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getSmallestAndLargest("welcometojava", 3);
    }

    public static String getSmallestAndLargest(String s, int k) {
        String smallest = "";
        String largest = "";
        smallest = largest = s.substring(0, k);
        for (int i = 1; i < s.length() - k + 1; i++) {
            String substr = s.substring(i, i + k);
            if (smallest.compareTo(substr) > 0)
                smallest = substr;
            if (largest.compareTo(substr) < 0)
                largest = substr;
            System.out.println("i=" + i + ", substring=" + substr + ", smallest=" + smallest + ", largest=" + largest);
        }
        return smallest + "\n" + largest;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
i=1, substring=elc, smallest=elc, largest=wel
i=2, substring=lco, smallest=elc, largest=wel
i=3, substring=com, smallest=com, largest=wel
i=4, substring=ome, smallest=com, largest=wel
i=5, substring=met, smallest=com, largest=wel
i=6, substring=eto, smallest=com, largest=wel
i=7, substring=toj, smallest=com, largest=wel
i=8, substring=oja, smallest=com, largest=wel
i=9, substring=jav, smallest=com, largest=wel
i=10, substring=ava, smallest=ava, largest=wel
```

In a similar way, you can add some more print statements e.g. to print the value of `smallest.compareTo(substr) > 0` and so on to trace your code to a deeper level. However, I strongly recommend you use a debugger to do so.

Comment: @Arvind Kuman Avinash Thankyou